# How to convert a manifold definition in a more handle or conventional one?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds

My concerns are about the definition given in Jeff. M Lee's book about Manifolds. He uses a definition to chart $(U, \phi), \phi: U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that ignores homeomorphism, because, for him, we don't have a topology a priori, which is yielded after building compatible charts and then an atlas and inducing a topology using the domains of the charts on a maximal atlas as a base for the topology in the manifold. The main problem is, what conditions I have to set in this topology, now induced, so that I indeed get charts that are nicer homeomorphisms $\phi$ instead of only bijections from a set $U\subset M$ to an open euclidian set? Which kind of equivalence is behind this definition and the usual definition to smooth manifolds which consider charts as homeomorphisms? Can I use both, or I have to be more careful and introduce some additional properties to convert one in the other? Below are shown definitions I mentioned in J. Lee: [image]

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Manifolds can be characterized entirely in terms of charts, but some additional assumptions are needed to ensure the resulting topology is well-behaved. Lemma 1.35 in John Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* gives one example of how to do this.

Comment: I just saw this Lemma. It has exactly the same assumptions that Jefrrey Lee uses. But, the topology induced in the manifold is slightly different, while Jeffrey Lee considers the set of domains of the charts as a basis, John Lee induces the topology using preimages of each open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for each chart. The later indeed offers a homeomorphis as a consequence but I stuck in see how can I get the same using the former topology.

Comment: Using only the chart domains as a basis for the topology only makes sense if the atlas is required to be maximal. In that case, every preimage of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the domain of a chart.

Comment: I agree that the atlas must be maximal. But, how could you conclude in this case that every preimage of an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the domain of a chart? If possible, please, could you explain it?

Comment: Given a maximal atlas, a chart $\varphi:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and an open set $V\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $U'=\varphi^{-1}(V)$, the restriction $\varphi|_{U'}:U'\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a chart which is smoothly compatible with the atlas.

Comment: Using definition 1.25 above to this chart you gave be compatible with the atlas, we have to satisfy condition (ii). That is, $\phi(U'\cap W)$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for every other chart $\psi: W\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it clear why this condition is indeed satisfied? For me it is not clear yet. But could be the case and thus the problem is solved!

Comment: Injective maps have the property $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$. Since charts are injective, we have $$\varphi(U'\cap W)=V\cap\varphi(U\cap W)$$

Comment: I don't have anything more to say, that is perfect! Now, things sounds more peaceful with this definition 1.25. Thank you very much @Kajelad!

Comment: I don't have access to Lee's book. Does he prove that for each atlas $\mathcal A$ on the set $M$ there exists a **unique topology** on $M$ such that (1) all $U_\alpha$ are open in $M$ (2) all $x_\alpha :U_\alpha \to x_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ become homeomorphisms?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, provided the transition functions are continuous. There are additional requirements, however, to ensure that the resulting topology is Hausdorff and second countable.

Comment: @Kajelad Okay, in Definition 1.25 the transition functions are continuous. Anyway, for **topologizing** $M$ we do not need additional conditions. Such conditions only assure that the resulting space is a manifold in the usual sense.

Comment: @Kajelad You should consider to give an official answer.